# Stop propagation for ionic2 event

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I am using ionic2 and angularjs2 with typescript. I have a list with-in list.
So something like :

```
    .A
    . A1
    . A2
    ..... A21
    ..... A22
    .B
    .C
    . C1
    . C2
```

I am reordering the list using

```
    < ion-list reorder="true" (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)" >
```

I even tried

```
    ion-item-group
```

Works fine. Does not work properly with nested list.

Whenever i reorder the sub-list, the main list also get reordered.
My reorderItems method looks like:

```
reorderItems(event){

    this.itemTree = reorderArray(this.itemTree, event);

}
```

There is no stopPropagation and preventDefault method on ionItemReorder event.

How do i go about it? Or should i be using some other component? If yes, which component should i use?

Comment: The problem is the ionItemReorder event does not have `stopPropagation()`. It gives me this error:

([15:03:02.257] Error: EXCEPTION: Error in app/***.html:15:31
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: event.stopPropagation is not a function

ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object])